# AngularJS Protractor element by.model can't find element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

using the element(by.model()) syntax to find a field and input text.

**element(by.model('sample_ad.id')).sendKeys('batman');**

gets the exception from chromedriver:

```
Stacktrace:
     Error: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds
    at Error (<anonymous>)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at Protractor.waitForAngular (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:278:22)
    at Protractor.findElement (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:427:8)
    at Object.elementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:62:21)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/test/e2e/features/somedirectiveSpec.js:24:39)
    at /Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:54:12
==== async task ====
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/jasminewd/index.js:53:12)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jon/dev/project_name/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/minijasminenode/lib/async-callback.js:45:37)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Not sure why this is breaking, but Protractor seems very fragile right now... **I have no issues using the browser object to find elements, input text, etc...**

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: if I change the line to the following, I am able to interact with the text field.
browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('sample_ad_id')).sendKeys('batman');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#my-tests-time-out-in-protractor-but-everythings-working-fine-when-running-manually-whats-up

for more information on timeouts.

Comment: I found a controller which someone had written which was using timeouts, and in the $timeout(function(){...}) it was calling the a function which created a loop (basically mimicking $interval)... i switched this over to interval and no longer have to use browser.ignoreSynchronization=true

Answer (score 3):

hopefully this will help others....

Found this on github (see references link).  The issue I believe is a script not returning, thus the sendKeys didn't work.  Before interacting with the dom using protractor objects (element, ptor, etc), set this variable:

**browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;**

The reason the following works is because it doesn't rely on async calls, its just directly interacts with the dom and inserts the keys into the input field.
**browser.driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('sample_ad_id')).sendKeys('batman');**

The reason my call didn't work (*I believe*) is because there was an async call that didn't return in time.
**element(by.model('sample_ad.id')).sendKeys('batman');**

references:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/325

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your test is timing out. The default timeout for protractor is 11 seconds.

Try setting a different timeout for this test:

```
it('should override timeout', function() {
  // Timeout of 30 seconds.
  element(by.model('sample_ad.id')).sendKeys('batman');
}, 30000)
```

You can also override the timeout for all your tests in the protractor configuration file. See this sample config file:

https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-meetup/blob/master/protractor-config.js#L19

```
// Inside the protractor config file.
onPrepare: function() {
  // Override the timeout for webdriver.
  var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
  ptor.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
}
```

Comment: After using this - it took a lot longer to timeout than before...

From what I can tell, this isn't a timeout issue - its the ptor functions not being able to finish execution before timing out... my guess is they will never finish.  Just not sure why...